# UITableView dynamic cell content

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I use to create a `UITableView` with the labels created using `NSArray`. Followed the tutorial [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/). Now I'm trying to create `UITableView` with dynamic content extracted from my server. The pulling of data works nicely with JSON that i assign as such:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",responseString1);

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    id sample = [parser objectWithString:responseString1];

    tempholder=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sample count]];

    for (int i = 0; i < [sample count]; i++) {
        [tempholder addObject:[[sample objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0]];
        //NSLog(@"%@",[sample objectAtIndex:i]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[tempholder objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}
```

So how do i replace the

```
tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Item", @"Item",
            @"Item", @"Item", @"Item", @"Item", @"Item",
            @"Item", @"Item", nil];
```

which is in my

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

with the 'tempholder' `NSMutableArray`?

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Is tableData the array you use to load your cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the tempHolder array as your tableData and then reload the table view at the end of your connectionDidFinishLoading: method.

```
tableData = tempholder;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

After you are done parsing your JSON, add this:

```
self.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempholder];
```

Then you'll probalby want to relaod your table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSMutableArray pretty much wherever you used NSArray.  Replace your tableData references with tempholder (or rename tempholder to be more meaningful). Conversely, If you really need to, you can also set tableData to be tempholder.

Answer (score 1):

in your code you have initialize NSArray in viewDidLoad metho

```
tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Item", @"Item", @"Item", @"Item", @"Item", @"Item", @"Item", @"Item", @"Item", nil];
```

instead of NSArray use NSMutableArray for it.

then when you receive data from server, just do following

```
[tableData removeAllObjects];
tableData = tempholder
```

Comment: because you can not edit NSArray, while NSMutableArray allows editing later on.

Comment: its must be of type NSMutableArray then you can removeAllObjects.